# I need help creating a specific type of background in photoshop for a packaging mockup

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to create a background similar to the one attached, but I am not sure how. Please help. Hopefully someone can explain how to, or can link me to a site/video on how to do this. Thank you.  [image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here we have 2 layers Upper and Lower.

- click to have black and white foreground and background colors
- drag a slightly different black to white linear gradients to both layers. The direction can be slightly tilted and a radial gradient also can be useful.
- select and delete a part of the upper layer at the bottom or alternatively drag the Upper layer contet partially out of the image
- Take the curves tool Turn the black to white gradients to proper grey to other grey gradients by tweaking the curve. I have moved the ends.

You can also spray some irreqularity by having very large and soft brush with low opacity.

Merge the layers after you are sure "this it is". There's no need to hurry.

If you add a white background layer, you can easily make the appearance lighter by decreasing the opacities of layers Upper and Lower.

Another example with painted irreqularities and the white addition:

[image]